# How to get GAE's row id?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

Here is my table in Google App Engine:

```
class Article:
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    text = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then I render this to front:

```
articles = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Article ORDER BY created DESC")
self.render("index.html", articles=articles)
```

And How can I get this row's id ?Like this:

```
{% for article in articles %}
{{ article.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the id like this:

```
article.key.id()
```

Take a look at the documentation on [Entities, Properties, and Keys](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/entities).